# Make TinyMCE output single spans instead of wrapper spans

Tags: javascript, tinymce

Is there any way/configuration to make tinyMCE output single spans instead of multiple spans or a way to do the same using javascript(some library)?

For example tinyMCE gives me this output

```
<p> 
  <span style="font-style: italic;">Hi How Are <span style="font-weight: bold;">you</span>?</span>
</p>
```

Instead i need output in format:

```
<p>
  <span style="font-style: italic;">Hi How Are </span>
  <span style="font-weight: bold;font-style: italic;">you</span>
  <span style="font-style: italic;">?</span>
</p>
```

As you can see I need to apply the style applied on outer span to every span and then split them to single ones. I have looked at the configurations but couldn't find anything for the same.
My current TinyMCE configuration is:

```
mode : "textareas",
theme : "simple",
formats : {
       bold : {inline : 'span', styles : {fontWeight : 'bold'}},
       italic:{inline : 'span', styles : {fontStyle:'italic'}}
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunatly, this desired behaviour is not available out of the box. I suggest you ask in the tinymce forum and [vote for this feature request](http://www.tinymce.com/develop/bugtracker_features.php#!order=desc&column=number&filter=nested%20span&status=open,verified&type=feature) at the tinymce website. It is the one with id bug 5411. (You might need to create a tinymce user account).
I had the same need for not-nested spans, but had to develop a plugin of my own.
The idea is pretty much to overwrite the Formatter.js-file to not nest spans, which has been a very tricky task.

**Update**: I guess it might be of help to you if i give you my Formatter class. Be aware this class is not up-to-date with the newest tinymce version of Formatter.js, it may lack functionality (even though i did not encounter anything yet). I kept the german comments in the code out of lazyness.

Unfortunatly, SO offers only limited space to be posted, so i put the class code and pasted it here: http://fiddle.tinymce.com/2tcaab  .

Comment: thanks will vote for the issue and later fiddle with Formatter.js

Comment: please, please don't forget to vote for the feature request 5411 (http://www.tinymce.com/develop/bugtracker_features.php#!order=desc&column=number&filter=nested%20span&status=open,verified&type=feature)